# How to get back top menu bar after it disappears while using Firefox?

Tags: firefox, menu, fullscreen, menu-bar

My webpages are being displayed without the Firefox borders, and I can't view the applications, places and system bar on the top. I accidentally pressed some button and I can't get the default settings back.

Comment: You probably pressed F11.... Press it again

Comment: Close-voters: This particular question *clearly* applies to currently supported releases also, and the solution is known. There is no reason to close this. **anjani singh**: With that said, you should definitely not use the desktop version of Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. 10.04 remains supported *only* for server systems with out GUIs running a very small subset of all packages. Your system doesn't updates for newly found security vulnerabilities, so using it is risky. You should use a currently supported release of *some* operating system instead; I recommend just upgrading to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

As [Seth says](https://askubuntu.com/questions/341699/system-settings-in-unbuntu-10-4#comment436658_341699), Firefox is probably in full screen mode. <kbd>F11</kbd> both enters and leaves full screen mode. So try pressing <kbd>F11</kbd>. That's probably the button you pressed by accident; pressing it again should bring you back to normal windowed mode.